# jquery remove text partially

Tags: jquery

Can i use jQuery to remove part of a text within a div.

Like so:

```
<div class="entry">
Published May 18th 2011 - Approuved - Expire May 18 th 2012<br>Source: SuperSite
</div>
```

I would like to remove **Approuved - Expire May 18 th 2012**

So the result would be:

```
 <div class="entry">
    Published May 18th 2011 <br>Source: SuperSite
    </div>
```

Comment: Is the contents of the div dynamic or static?

Comment: dynamic for the date "May 18th 2011", "May 18 th 2012" and "SuperSite"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use jquery to select your element/html, but javascript has a builtin function `replace` that will do what you need:

```
$('div.entry').html($('div.entry')
                          .html()
                          .replace('Approuved - Expire May 18 th 2012', ''))
```

Or using `RegExp`:

If what you want to replace starts always with `Approuved - Expire`:

```
$('div.entry').html($('div.entry')
                          .html()
                          .replace(/Approuved - Expire[^<]*/, ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".entry").html(function(i, htm){
   return htm.split("-")[0];
});
```

html() can also have a function passed on to it if you want to process the html inside a node and then reset it.

Here is a demo on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nKJWn/

Comment: i would like to keep Source: SuperSite

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".entry").html(($(".entry").html().replace("Approuved - Expire May 18 th 2012","")))
```

Comment: the date May 18 th 2012 is dynamic