# jquery .html function remove part of a text within a div

Tags: jquery

in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263632/jquery-remove-text-partially) one suggested to do:

```
$(".entry").html(function(i, htm){
   return htm.split("-")[0];
});
```

To remove **Approuved - Expire May 18 th 2012** but this remove 
Source: SuperSite also and i would like to keep the source

```
<div class="entry">
Published May 18th 2011 - Approuved - Expire May 18 th 2012<br>Source: SuperSite
</div>
```

I would like to remove **Approuved - Expire May 18 th 2012**

So the result would be:

```
<div class="entry">
    Published May 18th 2011 <br>Source: SuperSite
    </div>
```

Comment: why not use @manji answer that do exactly what you ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".entry").html(function(i, htm){
  var retStr = htm.split("-")[0]
  return retStr+htm.split("<br>")[1];
});
```

You return only what is placed before the first '-'. You have to add what it's placed after 
the `<br>` tag.
Code snippet is only for give you an idea. It's a little bit dirty but you can start from it.

Answer (score 0):

May ne you might try:

```
return htm.replace(/-[^<]+?/, '');
```